# Timed alert box pop up for website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, alert

For my website I would like an alert box message to appear 4 seconds after the page is opened. I cant figure out how to do this as the timed function works if a button is clicked but I would like the alert box to pop up automatically withoutt any user input/button and then shut when the user clicks "okay"...

Any ideas or posts related to this topic would be great help!

Thanks

Comment: What have you got so far?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){setTimeout(showPopup,4000)};

function showPopup()
{
   //write functionality for the code here
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks great answer, it was the windows.onload I think I was looking for.

Comment: @Belasyse93 : Glad that I could be of help.

Answer (score 4):

In it's most simple form:

```
setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello")},4000);
```

4000 = 4 seconds

Answer (score 2):

If you want an alert to appear after a certain about time use this code:

```
setTimeout(function() { alert("Your Message"); }, time);
```